# How do I use SimplSockets with a delegate for a "hello world" project?

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, tcp

I’m looking into the [SimplSockets](https://github.com/ironyx/simplsockets) library for building an application that uses sockets. However, after checking [other questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simplsocket), [the author’s blog](http://www.haneycodes.net/), [the source](https://github.com/ironyx/simplsockets), and several Internet searches, I can’t find a straightforward way to create a “hello world” project using SimplSockets.

**How do I create a “hello world” application that uses SimplSockets?**

To prevent a "too broad" closure, all I want to do is send and receive some data.  A string, whatever.  The reason I opened this question is because I'm unsure on how to call the constructor since it uses `func<T>` where `T` is a socket.

Comment: As phrased, this question is off topic for SO.  Recommendations for software/tutorials... etc.

Comment: @paqogomez: You may have gotten that impression by the word ‘sample’; but the question is just as valid if you replace the ‘sample’ with asking *how* it is to be done. With that adjustment made, it may still be too broad, but it is certainly not a request for an off-site resource.

Comment: Backlink to meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267590/328397 for people reviewing the close queue

Comment: @paqogomez -- for me, your comment makes absolutely on sense.  OP is not "asking for software or tutorials".  makerofthings7 - great question, thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow, Check the edit history of the question. By the time paqogomez wrote his/her answer, the question sounded a lot different.

Comment: Thanks @ebb, yes, this question is very different from the first version, hence the use of the "As phrased" phrase.  I was sure that as a 9k user, maker could bring it around.  I've retracted my close vote.  Nice to be able to ask meta for help as well, that seems to have garnered him 85 points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue I had with SimplSockets is that I didn’t properly understand how to use the delegate needed in the constructor.

Below is a sample client/server that echoes the data typed back at you.  I have no idea what I should be doing instead of `Thread.Sleep()`, so I’ll leave that there unless someone has a better suggestion.

```
private static void ConnectUsingSimpleSockets()
{
    int maxClients = 50;
    int maxPeers = 10;

    var socketCreator = () => new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    using (var client = new SimplSockets.SimplSocket(socketCreator, 5000, 10, true))
    {
        client.MessageReceived += client_MessageReceived;
        client.Error += client_Error;

        var ss = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(BitConverter.ToInt32(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1").GetAddressBytes(), 0), 4747);
        if (client.Connect(ss))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type something..");
            while (true)
            {
                string resul = Console.ReadLine();

                byte[] data = client.SendReceive(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Client Send: " + resul + DateTime.Now));

                if (data == UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("END"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));

            }
        }
        client.Close();


        client.Listen(ss);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sleeping");
            Thread.Sleep(7000);
        }
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... Is `client.MessageReceived += client_MessageReceived` adding the delegate that the `SimplSocket` constructor would not take?

Comment: I think it should be `BitConverter.ToInt64`