# How do I call the following constructor Func<T> as in SimplSocket(Func<System.IO.Sockets.Socket> socketFunc)

Tags: c#, sockets, func

I'm not familiar with this API, but I'm trying to create a new constructor that requires a parameter of Func as shown in the constructor below

```
public SimplSocket(System.Func<System.Net.Sockets.Socket> socketFunc, 
                   int messageBufferSize, 
                   int maximumConnections, 
                   bool useNagleAlgorithm)
```

What do I do with `socketFunc`?

Comment: I don't follow you.  What are you trying to do again?  Are you trying to instantiate `SimplSocket`, subclass it, or overload another constructor?

Comment: @KirkWoll I'm trying to instantiate SimplSocket http://stackoverflow.com/q/25087508/328397

Comment: You need to pass it a method (or a lambda) that takes no parameters and returns a new socket.  That methods would be the argument for parameter `socketFunc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Func<System.Net.Sockets.Socket>` is a so called delegate. They are used to hold functions. In this special case the delegate only accepts functions that return a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` type and that have no arguments. For example:

You have a function defined somewhere:

```
public System.Net.Sockets.Socket someFunction()
{
  //whatever it does
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var sock = new SimplSocket(someFunction, 1024,1,false);
```

If you don't want to define an extra function you could use lambda expression to express the function directly:

```
var sock = new SimplSocket(() => new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(...), 1024,1,false);
```

The constructor itself can use delegate `socketFunc` to call the given function and it knows that the function will return a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` but doesn't know which function is used. This would simply look like this:

```
 var aSock = socketFunc();
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the term so I can google-fo it...the example was great thank you

Comment: Is there a known design pattern that explains the why or when to apply this type of use of delegates in a constructor? I have just started working on a new project, and i am starting to see a lot of these constructs from other developers, yet i don't fully understand what the intention behind is.